# What do groundhogs and other subsurface-tunnel dwelling creatures do in heavy rains to avoid harm?

Tags: entomology, ecology, behaviour, mammals

I notice groundhogs and many other tunneling creatures in my yard, the same yard which became pretty flooded during heavy rainfall. I don't see wildlife out during rain storms, but not long after, they emerge and return to their regular daily behavior.

What do the creatures living in tunnels underground do to avoid harm from flooding? The kind of harm I imagine them being susceptible to is drowning or damage to their tunnel. It could be that their tunnels get destroyed and they simply dig their way out and make a new one, in which case the only remaining question is how they avoid drowning while sheltering underground from storms. Even that question may be moot if they don't in fact shelter underground from storms, but instead shelter somewhere less susceptible to inundation like up in a tree.

I originally had groundhogs in mind with this question, but if possible, I'm interested in answers that apply to various tunnel dwellers: groundhogs, chipmunks, ants, ground wasps, etc. I know many ground-dwelling insects live there for the moisture it provides, and during storms they'll come to the surface to enjoy the moisture there and avoid drowning (e.g. slugs, worms), but I don't think this applies to all insects and certainly doesn't apply to mammals who generally seek shelter from the rain.